# Artefacts/traces when using both animation and stylesheets on PieChart

Tags: javafx

When I use both css and animations on my pieChart I get these strange artefacts. Anyone ever noticed these and how to eventually fix them? The code I use for setting the stylesheet is:

```
  String styleString = "-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 3; -fx-border-style: dashed;";
```

The animation code is pulled from http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/11/21/animating-the-javafx-piechart-a-bit/ and customised - works great !

[image]

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem and got different, but similar artefacts. Could you try to set the BlendMode of your Data Nodes to `SRC_OVER` or `SRC_ATOP` and check if that makes a difference?

Comment: The answer is src-atop then, you should add it, so you get the points :)  Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the [BlendMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/BlendMode.html) of the Data nodes to `SRC_ATOP`. This works for me when I try to recreate the problem.